# Magento 2: quote data is not working with cache enable

Tags: magento2, cache, quote

I tried the below code but when the cache is disabled. it works, but when I enable cache it does not work.
[Overview of retrieving the data of shopping cart items, subtotal, grand total, billing & shipping address in Magento 2](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-data-shopping-cart-items-subtotal-grand-total-billing-shipping-address-magento-2.html)

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
echo $totalItems = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCount();
echo $totalQuantity = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsQty();
```

> I know that we do not use an object manager. I will change the code.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't with cache enabled, all files aren't re-interpreted.

You should get it with customer data. You can try to add the following code in your phtml file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
    ], function (customerData) {
        'use strict';

        customerData.get('cart').subscribe(function (cartInfo) {
            console.log(cartInfo['summary_count']);
        }, this);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this code will help you!!

```
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

        // get quote items collection
        $itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

        // get array of all items what can be display directly
        $itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

        // get quote items array
        $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

        foreach($items as $item) {
/*for example below attribute access it*/
            echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
            echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
            echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
            echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
            echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
            echo "<br />";            
        }
```

**I hope this will help you!!**

Comment: Thanks! For the reply.
I applied the same logic if you can check the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
$totalItems = $cart->getQuote();
$quoteItems= $totalItems->getAllItems();

  foreach ($quoteItems as $item ){
        echo $item->getQty();
  }
```